# How to apply an if between function on a column in pandas' DataFrame

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to change a numeric column into a categorical one by applying if the value is in range 4 to 8 then "yes" else "No"
what is the simplest way to do that????
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you show me what your input file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Numbers = {'set_of_numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = DataFrame(Numbers,columns=['set_of_numbers'])

df.loc[4 <= df.set_of_numbers <= 8, 'equal_or_lower_than_4?'] = 'True' 
df.loc[df.set_of_numbers < 4, 'equal_or_lower_than_4?'] = 'False'
df.loc[df.set_of_numbers > 8, 'equal_or_lower_than_4?'] = 'False' 

print (df)
```

Comment: Might be a better way of doing this but this looks like the simples way of getting what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Python’s `numpy` module provide a function to select elements based on condition i.e.

```
numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
```

**Argument:**
*condition* : A condional expression that returns a Numpy array of bool
x, y : Arrays (Optional i.e. either both are passed or not passed)

- If all arguments –> condition , x & y are passed in numpy.where() then it will return elements selected from x & y depending on values in bool array yielded by condition. All 3 arrays must be of same size.
- If x & y arguments are not passed and only condition argument is passed then it returns a tuple of arrays (one for each axis) containing  the indices of the elements that are True in bool numpy array returned by condition.

**Example:**

```
s = pd.Series(range(5))
s.where(s > 1, 10)
```

Output:

```
0    10
1    10
2    2
3    3
4    4
```